# CSS grid creating disproportionate layouts when using fractions and screen size percentage

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I have been having some trouble getting CSS Grid to work properly with my React App. When I use `grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;`, one of the `1fr` columns is much smaller than the other (so the space on the right is much smaller than the space created on the left in comparison to the middle column). Is there any particular reason why this would be? Here is the rest of my CSS:

```
#main-body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

#main-header {
  color: white;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
}

#quote-render-block {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be another child react component apart from the main-body or some styling for the parent component that is creating the issue. You can view a codepen of your code here: https://codepen.io/sakettawde/pen/yxvoxM

HTML:

```
<div class="main-body">
  <div class="main-header">
    </div>
  <div class="quote-render-block">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

.main-header {
  color: white;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
}

.quote-render-block {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you were right - margin and padding of body were not set to 0. I thought it might have had to do something with React, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that a parent element has a "padding-right" CSS attribute that is shifting the contents of the screen.